# SQL Multiple Pivot

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I have the below data set in a Microsoft SQL Server (`table A`) and am trying to pivot on both columns `ID_1` and `ID_2`.  I can pivot on one column but am having difficulty pivoting on a concatenated column.  Any help would be great appreciated.

What I have (`table A`):

```
Date     ID_1   ID_2    Value
1-Jan      1     a       77
1-Jan      1     b       113
1-Jan      1     c       212
2-Jan      1     a       159
2-Jan      1     b       85
2-Jan      1     c       46
3-Jan      1     a       300
3-Jan      1     b       456
3-Jan      1     c       100
```

What I need (`table B`):

```
Date    1_a 1_b 1_c
1-Jan   77  113 212
2-Jan   159 85  46
3-Jan   300 456 100
```

Comment: select 
Date,
[1] 
from tblA a
pivot(Max(a.Value) for a.ID_1 in ([1])) as pv
where Date between '1/1/2014' and '1/3/2014'

Comment: I just can't seem to figure out how to pivot on multiple levels

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9eecb/2521)

**Query 1**:

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE ([Date] VARCHAR(10),ID_1 INT, ID_2 CHAR(1), Value INT)
INSERT INTO @Table VALUES 
('1-Jan',      1     ,'a',       77  ),
('1-Jan',      1     ,'b',       113),
('1-Jan',      1     ,'c',       212),
('2-Jan',      1     ,'a',       159),
('2-Jan',      1     ,'b',       85),
('2-Jan',      1     ,'c',       46),
('3-Jan',      1     ,'a',       300),
('3-Jan',      1     ,'b',       456),
('3-Jan',      1     ,'c',       100)


SELECT *
FROM (
SELECT [Date] 
     , CAST(ID_1 AS VARCHAR(10)) + '_' + ID_2  AS Cols
     , Value
FROM @Table)t
 PIVOT (SUM(Value)
        FOR Cols 
        IN([1_a],[1_b],[1_c])
        )p
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9eecb/2521/0)**:

```
|  Date | 1_a | 1_b | 1_c |
|-------|-----|-----|-----|
| 1-Jan |  77 | 113 | 212 |
| 2-Jan | 159 |  85 |  46 |
| 3-Jan | 300 | 456 | 100 |
```